# Filter rows with cumsums Sales above... (dplyr)

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a data frame like this:

```
set.seed(1234)
Name <- c(rep("A", 4), rep("B", 4), rep("C", 4), rep("D", 4))
Month <- rep(c("M1","M2","M3","M4"), 4)
Sales <- sample(1000:10000, 16)
df <- data.frame(Name, Month, Sales)
```

I need to select rows where cumsum of all months Sales is greater than 23000. The result should look then:

```
Name Month Sales
C    M1  6990
C    M2  5624
C    M3  7236
C    M4  5899
D    M1  3541
D    M2  9299
D    M3  3627
D    M4  8523
```

The cumsum is the key I guess, but I can't get the right dplyr formula for filter.

Comment: There are two solutions one fit your desired output, mine not. As I read your description I do not understand the grouping operation, I just interpret it as *total cumsum of all sales*. Maybe further clarifications would be better.

Comment: This makes no sense.  Your desired result is just `df[df$Name %in% c("C", "D"), ]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try the following:

```
df %>% group_by(Name) %>% filter(sum(Sales) > 23000)
#Source: local data frame [8 x 3]
#Groups: Name
#
#  Name Month Sales
#1    C    M1  6990
#2    C    M2  5624
#3    C    M3  7236
#4    C    M4  5899
#5    D    M1  3541
#6    D    M2  9299
#7    D    M3  3627
#8    D    M4  8523
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a base R solution.

```
 ind <- cumsum(df$Sales) > 23000
 df[ind, ]
   Name Month Sales
5     B    M1  8745
6     B    M2  6760
7     B    M3  1085
8     B    M4  3091
9     C    M1  6990
10    C    M2  5624
11    C    M3  7236
12    C    M4  5899
13    D    M1  3541
14    D    M2  9299
15    D    M3  3627
16    D    M4  8523
```

Comment: Yep, that's what I got out of the question too

Comment: @RichardScriven at this point it could be great a clarification by the OP.